# deploying charms using juju fails with tcp connection timed out

Tags: 14.04, juju, maas

### Environment:

juju bootstrapped environment with MAAS [ Juju 1.19.x]

Connected to internet:

> wget
>   https://store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Atrusty%2Fjuju-gui-3

works with the charm meta as output.

Trying to deploy my first juju charm using command:

```
juju deploy juju-gui -e maas --debug -v
```

The following is the error:

```
2014-06-30 21:39:04 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:37 running juju [1.19.4-trusty-amd64 gc]
2014-06-30 21:39:04 DEBUG juju.conn api.go:187 trying cached API connection settings
2014-06-30 21:39:04 INFO juju.conn api.go:270 connecting to API addresses: [dc1dt8.maas:17070]
2014-06-30 21:39:04 INFO juju.state.api apiclient.go:242 dialing "wss://dc1dt8.maas:17070/"
2014-06-30 21:39:04 INFO juju.state.api apiclient.go:176 connection established to "wss://dc1dt8.maas:17070/"
2014-06-30 21:41:12 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:323 cannot download charm "cs:trusty/juju-gui-3": Cannot access the charm store. Are you connected to the internet? Error details: Get https://store.juju.ubuntu.com/charm-info?charms=cs%3Atrusty%2Fjuju-gui-3: dial tcp 91.189.95.67:443: connection timed out
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Was that `wget` command from your local workstation or from the `dc1dt8.maas` machine?

Comment: it was from dc1dt8.maas